# Uso del MANIFEST.MF (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, manifest

Estoy creando un fichero .jar, concretamente mejorando el código de uno existente. El problema es que al decompilar para obtener los .java, solo obtengo el código, nada de manifest, dependencias ni demás añadidos.

Con esto, he hecho las modificaciones pertinentes y funciona a la perfección al ejecutarlo desde mi eclipse, pero cuando creo el .jar y ejecuto el servicio anterior salta el siguiente mensaje Failed to load

```
Main-Class manifest attribute from
C:\orquestador\orquestador.jar
```

informándome veo que es por el fichero .mf, ya que no lo tengo... veo que creando manualmente no sirve, tiene que ser una estructura concreta, con el META-INF y ahí dentro del fichero.

Con esto sé que no es crear un proyecto java normal, tiene que ser algo más concreto dentro del menú de creación de proyectos de eclipse. Qué clase de proyectos puedo generar para crear un jar que inicie un servicio? Únicamente maven?

ACTUALIZACIÓN:

He creado el jar mediante cmd con jar -cf y asignado un manifest.mf con jar cmf, todas esas operaciones salieron a la perfección pero persiste en error:

```
Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal Principal
```

Mi fichero manifest:

```
Main-Class: Principal
```

(Tiene el retorno de carro al final, solo que no aparece en el texto de la página)

Comment: ¿Cómo ejecutas el jar? Generalmente cuando ejecutas un jar con java -jar tienes que especificar la clase donde tengas el método main, que es al fin y al cabo el punto de entrada de tu programa. El fichero manifest no suele ser necesario crearlo a mano, la herramienta con la que generes el jar debería ser capaz de generarlo. Si lo generas en eclipse, cuando vas a Export -> JAR File, si sigues todos los pasos del Wizard tienes una opción de generar el manifest y otra opción para seleccionar la clase principal del programa.

Comment: @ordago-QUÉDATEENCASA el problema está en cuando ejecuto con java-jar, aún indicando donde está la clase principal, que salta el siguiente error: "no hay ningún atributo de manifiesto principal en orquestador.jar", es como si no lo creara, por eso busco si puedo crear uno externamente y asignarlo.

Comment: Puedes añadir a tu manifest manualmente este atributo: Main-Class: Principal.class (suponiendo que en la clase Principal tienes tu método main). Un jar es un zip al fin y al cabo, por lo que si lo descomprimes puedes editar ese fichero y añadir ese atributo en el manifest. Después lo vuelves a comprimir con extensión jar. Aunque creo que es mucho más fácil generar el jar siguiendo todos los pasos de wizard cuando exportas el jar en Eclipse ¿no te funcionó haciéndolo así?

Comment: @ordago-QUÉDATEENCASA no funcionó, y no entiendo el motivo, ni con el wizzard. He actualizado la pregunta con nuevas cosas que probé, ahora ya con otro error, parece que detecta el manifest pero no la clase. Se va avanzando. Mil gracias!

Comment: Mira a ver si te sirve esto: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: el nombre de tu clase principal debe ser totalmente cualificado. Saludos.